# Battery Monitoring to detect low power state?

Tags: batteries, circuit-design

Our problem is corruption of battery due to reaching zero level of charge. We have tried many methods to monitor the battery as:

[How to detect low battery of a lead-acid battery?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67561/how-to-detect-low-battery-of-a-lead-acid-battery)

(using ADC and micro-controller). Now, we are using (IC - DS2788 E+) however though this type of monitoring circuits consume power. Is there any way to monitor the battery with minimum power overhead (e.g a couple micro-watts) and disconnect the battery?

Comment: Please provide all relevant information, like the model number and type of battery you have. Why would you want to monitor the batteries state if you aren't using it?

Comment: Our battery is Li-Polymer, honestly it is used for a power bank system, and we must protect the battery from being in state of zero charge (which damages the battery). We need something to check out the battery like every 5 minutes and remove it from circuit in case battery is too low. We have tried using micro controller, but is consumes power.

Comment: Consider the MSP430. You can achieve a standby of \$350\:\textrm{nA}\$, and lower, using their RTC. They can also go from this standby mode to full speed operation in about \$1\:\mu\textrm{s}\$. So, unlike the Microchip nanowatt devices which take a series of stages getting up to full speed and more time, you can greatly minimize the full power operation period, as well. If your duty cycle requires only once every 5 minutes, as you say, I think you can meet your goals with this family. It will depend on the rest of your surrounding circuitry, of course.

Comment: What's the Lipoly rail voltage? Are they stacked? Or just one?

Comment: How many cells are in your battery? Series or parallel or both?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. We use four 3.7 V cells in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Use a battery protection IC, such as those manufactured by Seiko. This is not intended to be an endorsement of a specific company. I just happen to be familiar with Seiko battery protection IC's.

http://www.sii-ic.com/en/semicon/products/power-management-ic/lithium-ion-battery-protection-ic/

Some of them have very low quiescent current.

Answer (score 0):

Using MCU doesn't look like the most efficient option. Personally I would prefer something called battery detector circuit (though there are many many different names and they all do pretty much the same thing). How does it work? Well, it's a simple comparator that outputs low or high voltage level dependent on whether there is sufficient voltage. Use this output to drive a MOSFET which can connect your load to battery and you will have a circuit that uses microamps or even less to monitor battery voltage.

Usually there are two types of such circuit - complementary logic (CMOS) or open-drain and either can be usable dependent of your design considerations